# Interpretation of Chu-Stinchcombe-White CUSUM Test results

Tags: time-series, factor-models, machine-learning

Context:
I am new to quant finance. I am doing some structural break analysis on a future price time series. I applied the  Chu-Stinchcombe-White CUSUM Test from Chap 17 (Advances in Financial Machine Learning by Marcos López de Prado), and the code was adopted from MlFinLab by Hudson and Thames. I got the following results, and I have difficulty interpreting why most of the S_nt stats are below the critical region and why the critical values have a partial circular sector trend.
[image]
I appreciate all the hints and answers!

Comment: Is it possible for you to include your code in the question?

Comment: @Pleb The code was directly adopted from https://github.com/hudson-and-thames/mlfinlab/issues/417. There is a file attached cusum.txt.